# React - Passing javascript element property down to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent element whose scrollTop I want available to its child component.

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body ref={(ref) => this.modalBody = ref}>
                    <ChildComponent modalBodyPosition={this.modalBody.scrollTop} />
                </Modal.Body>

                <Modal.Footer>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.modalBodyPosition);

        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
```

After searching around, I have not come across a way that actually works for me.  I have tried passing down a callback function but get React Instance errors when I do so.

The code above gives me null/undefined errors. Is there any way that I can access the `scrollTop` property on the HTML element down in the child components?

Note: I am using React 15 so I don't have access to the `React.createRef` function.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this very quickly, but it should be something like this:

```js
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    _handleScroll = () =>
      this.setState({modalBodyPosition: this.modalBody.scrollTop})
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body onScroll={this._handleScroll.bind(this)} ref={(ref) => this.modalBody = ref}>
                    <ChildComponent modalBodyPosition={this.state.modalBodyPosition} />
                </Modal.Body>

                <Modal.Footer>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.modalBodyPosition);

        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However, this doesn't quite work for me yet. I get `Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null` errors

Comment: `.bind(this)` is unnecessary since you're already defining an arrow function in the class component.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that the `handleScroll` function was a fat arrow function. I changed my code to reflect that and instead got this error: `Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled`.  I use fat arrow functions elsewhere in my actions file but for some reason React doesn't like it being used inside of a component.  Any ideas?

Comment: @noblerare the error has nothing to do with arrow functions, it's about [class properties](https://codeburst.io/use-class-properties-to-clean-up-your-classes-and-react-components-93185879f688).

Comment: I see. Thanks for that info. Is there any way to get around it? I'd rather not use experimental features in this bit of code.

Comment: @noblerare just `.bind(this)` in the constructor as usual. It's even shown in the link I shared.